# Communication between two computers and a database

Tags: sql, database, vb.net, user-interface

I'm a student programmer and I've landed a task at my job to develop a software system to monitor when employee's clock in, clock out, and log the times. The employee's will use a keypad attached to a computer at the front desk to enter their employee id into a gui which will clock them in/out. There's another gui the office manager will use to monitor employee in and outs, and keep track of who's in the office.

The project is a windows form project in VS 2010, with two gui's (as mentioned), and an Access 2007 database to store the data. The office manager gui has a DataGridView object that I'd like to populate with the employee name, and time (s)he clocks in or out. I would like for this to happen in real time. In other words, once the employee clocks in, it populates in the office managers gui. What I'm looking for is the best practice to this approach. Should I take a client/server approach? Should I have something trigger from the 
database to alert the office manager gui to fire an event to get the clock in/out time of the employee populated into the office managers DataGridView?

The database and queries have all been designed. I'm just looking for the best practice to approach this problem. I'm a junior level college student and I come to stackoverflow.com all the time. This is my first question, so either way this is a big step for me :) Thanks in advance.

Comment: MS Access is just not suitable for multi-computer scenarios. These mostly fall in multi-tier server client applications. access is good when one app in one one pc and saved/loads all data locally. not good in sending data to manager's table. could you consider using sql/server or mySQL or oracle? how about mysql? we can force ms-access in the way you want, but that is just not right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are Microsoft aligned (and are using .NET etc) you may find it easy enough to take the SQL Express route (all the tools Microsoft design are similar and integrate quite well together).

You can download SQL Express with advanced services (any version 2005 onwards should be fine for this project, as long as it includes management studio, and you might also want Reporting Services)

My approach would be to poll the database every now and then to monitor for changes in the clock in/out table(s).

I would not use access as it's not the best solution for an actual database and it doesn't scale particularly well. Whilst it will work fine for your project, it's worth getting your hands on SQL server just to get some experience with it.

I'm assuming your clocking in/out view will just show a page of employee names, and will be based on date - in which case firing a query every 5-10 seconds at the database to get the current state won't cause any issues.

Whilst it's possible to push notifications from SQL to the client, it is usually as easy if not easier to just rig a timer up at the client end and won't cause any performance impact in an application of this scale

Comment: OK, sounds simple enough. I'm a little familiar with databases and I failed to mention that it'll be migrated over to sql server 2008 or 2012 when it goes into production. I'll have to read up on database states, but thank you so much for your response.

Comment: By state I just mean a snapshot of the data at that time (a query in other words!) - nothing new to learn if you are already querying Access